# Leaflet routing machine Origine to destination

Tags: leaflet, routing, list

[image]
I want to do routing from a point to another the points are listed in legend control .the data retrieved from listbox does not work with routine machine may be because of type compatibility.

```
  var mymap=L.map('map',{attributionControl: false,center : [33.37,6.84],zoom: 12,minZoom:7,maxZoom: 17,zoomControl:false});
    var GRaster = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']}).addTo(mymap);
    function Itineraire(){
        var x = document.getElementById("Origin").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("Origin").options;    
        var x1 = document.getElementById("Destination").selectedIndex;
        var y1 = document.getElementById("Destination").options;

    //clear route
    Routing.getPlan().setWaypoints([]);
    //retrieve data
    var point1=y[x].value;
    var point2=y1[x1].value;

     alert('Routing :'+"pt1: "+y[x].value+" pt2: "+y1[x1].value);

    Routing.getPlan().setWaypoints([
    L.latLng(point1),
    L.latLng(point2)
    ]);
    }
    var Routing =L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
    L.latLng(33.357464,6.864267),
    L.latLng(33.374304,6.871693)
    ],
    routeWhileDragging: true
    });
    Routing.addTo(mymap);
    Routing.getPlan().setWaypoints([]);

    var legendbox = L.control({
    position: 'topleft'
    }); 

    legendbox.onAdd = function (e) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = '<select id=Origin><option value=33.374304,6.871693>Zone1</option><option value=33.367979,6.837744>Zone2</option><option value=33.372684,6.839808>Zone3</option></select><select id=Destination><option value=33.374304,6.871693>Zone1</option><option value= 33.367979,6.837744>Zone2</option></select>';
    div.innerHTML += '</br><button type = button onclick = Itineraire()> Find route </button>';
    div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return div;
    };
    legendbox.addTo(mymap);
```

[My running code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfZbfXrJrwtLCN1pxn3l?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was on retrieving javascript data from forms after the correction I got everything like I expected my code working.
[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/udkTIuGR3EH6B3GnowEv?p=preview)